# TableCellEditor doesn't show properly

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, nimbus

Im having trouble editing a cell, i'll picture cause my english is not very good.

[image: problem]

I add a `TableCellEditor` (extends a DefaultCellEditor, i know is not the best but the code is not mine). When i type letters are not ,

i tried to 
`table.setRowsHeight(comp.getHeight());`  works but i don't want this, i want the textfield fix in the row

So i tried to 
`comp.setPreferredSize(comp.getWidth(),table.getRowsHeight())` 
but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Sounds like a Nimbus issue I once encountered. Removing the border (`JTextField#setBorder( null )`) solved that issue

Comment: yeah that was it the first one :D post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue when using the Nimbus look-and-feel. Removing the border by calling

```
JTextField#setBorder( null )
```

solved it